# Client Object Model & CAML -> Getting Items of a specific view

Tags: list, client-object-model, view, caml

I need some support as I am struggling to understand what is wrong with my code. I try to retrieve the data of a specific view. The line

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery;
```

throws an exception `The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.` Obviously there is something wrong the way I am handling the view, any suggestions?

```
// ClientContext object is used to get the context for the SharePoint object 
// Create a client connection
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
//user login via Form Authentication 
clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo fba = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(siteUser, sitePassword);
clientContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = fba;

Web site = clientContext.Web;
List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
View view = list.Views.GetByTitle(ViewName);
ViewFieldCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields;

//Create the statement to retrieve the data
//pass  CamlQuery instance into a method on the List to retrieve the data.
//The return value from the GetItems method on the client OM’s List class is a ListItemCollection.  

//CamlQuery camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery;

//-----------------------
ListItemCollection ListColletion = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.Load(ListColletion);
clientContext.Load(viewFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using the property of the object which is not yet initialized. So to initialize this just write

```
  clientContext.Load(view);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

after the line:

View view = list.Views.GetByTitle(ViewName);

Comment: Yes! You made me a very happy man, thank you for the letting me know....